# Definite integral involving 2015

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Evaluate

$$\displaystyle\int_{2}^{2014} \frac{\log \left( 2015 - x\right )}{\log \left( 2015 - x\right ) + \log \left( x - 1\right )} \mathrm{d}x$$

I got the solution using software, and it is a nice number. But it should be solved by hand.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let the integral be $I$. Do the substitution $y=2016-x$. This leads to the integral
$$ I = \int_2^{2014} \frac{\log{(y-1)}}{\log{(y-1)}+\log{(2015-y)}} \, dy, $$
and you can relabel $y$ as $x$ and add together the two ways of writing $I$ to obtain
$$ 2I = \int_2^{2014} \frac{\log{(2015-x)}+\log{(x-1)}}{\log{(x-1)}+\log{(2015-x)}} \, dx = \int_2^{2014} 1 \, dx = 2012, $$
so $I = 1006$.

(This is an entirely standard trick for integrals containing $\frac{f(x)}{f(x) \pm f(b-x)}$.)